# Must a harmonic function that's positive and has positive normal derivative on the $x$-axis be positive in the entire upper half plane?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

I want to show that if $u(x,y)$, a twice differentiable function on the upper half plane, $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2\mid y \geq 0\},$ obeys the following conditions,

1. is harmonic, i.e. $(\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2)u=0$ everywhere on the upper half plane
2. $u(x,0)\geq 0$ on the $x$-axis
3. $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\bigg|_{y=0} \geq 0$ on the $x$-axis

then it will also obey $u(x,y) \geq 0$ everywhere on the upper half plane.

It *feels* intuitively obvious, with my loose intuitive grasp of the shape of harmonic functions on the plane: if one starts on the $x$-axis entirely positive with $u$ increasing everywhere as one steps into the upper plane, how could it possibly ever drop below the lowest value on the $x$-axis? Wouldn't that sort of depth have to *come* from somewhere? But beyond this intuition I've really made no progress. I've attempted some creative contours to use Stokes' and the Divergence theorem, but have come up with nothing. I don't know that much about partial differential equations - only as much as they teach in a physics undergraduate course - so I could be missing something obvious. Can it be proven? Is it true?

Comment: Do you know the Poisson kernel for the upper half plane?

Comment: I don't think so. How much choice is there? If it helps to define the problem better, the context of my question is about trying to analytically continue a complex function $f(x)$ on the real line to the upper complex plane, so $u(x,0)=\text{Im}\{f(x)\}$ and $\partial_yu(x,0) = \text{Re}\{\frac{df}{dx}\}$.  I want conditions on this function that, if satisfied, will mean its analytic continuation has always positive imaginary part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that $f(x,y)$ is harmonic and non-negative in the open half-plane $y > 0$, then there is a positive Lebesgue measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and a non-negative real constant $A$ such that
$$
              f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{y}{(x-x')^2+y^2}d\mu(x')+Ay,
$$
where $\mu$ satisfies
$$
             \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d\mu(t)}{1+t^2} < \infty.
$$
The components of this representation are unique. Conversely, any such representation gives a non-negative harmonic function in the open upper half-plane. This is a variant of a theorem of Gustav Herglotz from 1911.

The only significant difference between this case and yours is that you have added differentiability in the normal direction on the real axis. You don't need to impose differentiability in the normal direction in order to end up with a non-negative harmonic function. Differentiability in the normal direction would seem to require that $\mu(-\infty,t]$ is differentiable in $t$ on $\mathbb{R}$, and vice-versa, which would then reduce the integral to a classic Poisson integral of a non-negative continuous function $\rho(t)$ for which $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\rho(t)}{1+t^2}dt < \infty$, plus $Ay$ where $A$ is a non-negative constant.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I understand. Just to be sure - this is all quite new to me - the value of $f$ on the real line is given by $\rho(x)$, correct? (For some context, my interest in the normal derivative is from the fact that I'm using this result to get an analytic extension of a complex function $f(x)$ on the real line to the upper complex plane: my function $u=\text{Im}\{f(x)\}$ and its normal derivative is $\text{Re}\{f(x)\}$.)

Comment: Also, is there a tacit assumption about $f(x,y)$'s behaviour at infinity?  This is something I'm hoping to prove, so I don't want to put in sensible behaviour at infinity as an assumption at the start!

Comment: *I meant that the normal derivative is $\text{Re}\{\frac{df}{dx}\}$, which I think is just the Cauchy-Riemann equations

Comment: @J_B_Phys : The first formula for the representation is completely general in that it only requires $f(x,y)$ to be defined on the open upper half-plane, where it is assumed to be harmonic. The measure $\mu$ is unique and satisfies $\int \frac{d\mu(t)}{1+t^2} < \infty$. From this there is a known behavior of $f$ as $y\uparrow\infty$, for example. Added assumptions put more restrictions on $\mu$, as I mentioned.

Comment: Interesting. So if one specifies $\rho(x)$ on the real line, assuming only that it has *some* normal derivative, then the harmonic function is completely specified? Have you got any idea what would happen if you tried to specify both a general function *and* normal derivative on the real line and "propagate up", treating it like a wave equation with initial conditions? Locally, next to the real line, it seems inarguable that this is possible, so presumably you'd run into problems at some finite point up in the plane - divergences or something would inevitably appear?

Comment: @J_B_Phys : Positive harmonic functions in the upper half plane are determined by a charge distribution on the real line. The only ambiguity is the one positive harmonic function that vanishes on the real axis--namely $f(x,y)=Ay$ where $A$ is a positive real constant. This theorem of Herglotz is a powerful representation theorem because it requires no assumptions other than positivity of the harmonic function. This representation can be used to prove the general spectral theorem for unbounded self-adjoint linear operators on a Hilbert Space. That's how I encountered this result.

Comment: Alright, brilliant, thank you very much for your help! It is a much more powerful result than I was expecting, and I think it'll have some unexpected implications on my problem. Time to work out what those are!

Comment: @J_B_Phys : You'll notice that there is a conservation law built into this. If $A=0$, then $\lim_{y\uparrow\infty}y\phi(x,y)=\mu(\mathbb{R})$. That is, the total charge is the same as a limit at $\infty$. This is how the spectral theorem is proved: An integral with respect to a measure on the real line is given by a residue at $\infty$. This turns into Parseval's equality for general Fourier transforms. It's hard to explain in a few words, and it's rather amazing. Electrostatics rocks!!